# Safari 9 fails querySelectorAll with :invalid selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

Consider this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ngsTrIb1DI5te5H/veqLhnmp/

It has six fields with the `required` attribute. Using jQuery I set an event handler for the `change` event that writes out to the console how many required invalid fields are left. It works perfectly in EVERY other browser except Safari (or the new IE6 as I have begun to call it). Safari returns the wrong number half of the time.

How do I get around this? My ultimate goal is to simply ask jQuery to tell me if there's invalid required fields in a container element.

Comment: are you getting any console errors in safari? or just not the expected outcome?

Comment: No console errors, just not the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @user2182349, I had an idea, so I modified my jQuery selector extension to:

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    invalid: function (
        element) {
        return (element.validity && !element.validity.valid) || false;
    }
});
```

At first it didn't work with the select element because Safari was lagging behind the value setting as with all other attempts. BUT! When I added the `|| false` at the end, it suddenly started working for select elements as well (on a timely manner). As far as I'm concerned the functionality I've been looking for (and have spent the last six hours or so trying to make work) is finally available, so I'm calling it good.

Answer (score 1):

Safari doesn't support form validation completely (ref:http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ainvalid)

This isn't a perfect solution, but it may help:

```
  // All the elements which are required and lack a value attribute
  var empties = $("[required] [value]").not();

  // Count the number of selects
  var selects = $("select").length;

  // Count the number of selected options
  var selected = $("option[selected]").length;

  if (selected < selects) // One of the selects hasn't been selected
```

This approach won't be very reliable if there are multiselects, and checking only for the presence of data isn't very rigorous validation.

Comment: You gave me an idea that has promise, but the only thing stopping it now, is that on the `change` event Safari will still report that there's no option selected for the select element even though there is. It's like it's lagging behind what's actually happening. Any tips on that issue?

Comment: How are you testing which option is selected?